# Poisson Point Process Inhomogeneous Rate

Tags: probability-theory, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I can't seem to find how to derive this equation:

$$Pr(X(t)=n) = \frac1{n!}\left(\int_{0}^t \lambda(\tau) d\tau\right)^n\exp\left(-\int_{0}^t \lambda(\tau) d\tau\right)$$

Where $X(t)$ is the number of events over a time $t$.

The proof for a homogeneous rate $\lambda$ involves looking at the Binomial distribution where each trial is a small interval $\Delta$t. However, obviously that won't work in this case as the intervals won't have the same success rates.

Comment: you can format $exp$ appropriately by replacing with `$\exp$`

Comment: Also, to make "flexible brackets" that automatically adjust to fit the "innards", use `\left(... \right)`;  also works for `\left\{... \right\}` and can be used in the same manner to square brackets.

Comment: Did you intend to bracket/curly brace the entire right side, or to enclose the entire fraction in braces?  I see you used, braces.

Comment: No, I usually put my probabilities inside curly brackets but it seemed to messing with the formatting so I just used normal brackets.

Comment: Well, I'll delete them here, then.  It was just fine without them!  Just remember that curly brackets won't render unless immediately preceded by a back-slash.

Comment: @JohnMeighan, you are missing a negative sign in $\exp$. Also, to answer your question, it depends how they defined a Poisson process with rate $\lambda(t)$ for you. What you are asking is basically [the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Inhomogeneous_Poisson_point_process), meaning that you can't prove it.

Comment: Determine  the PGF and from the functional form of the PGF, interpret the probability function of the process.

Comment: The intuition for this formula is that an inhomogeneous Poisson process with rate $\lambda(s)$ has the same distribution, at a single time $t$, as a homogeneous Poisson process with rate equal to the average of the rate of the inhomogeneous process on $[0,t]$. This requires proof of course but this is the idea.

Answer (score 1):

In Homogeneous Poisson Process(HPP), the intensity parameter is a constant.

Non-Homogeneous Poisson Process(NHPP) is a generalization of Poisson Process, in the sense that, it allows the intensity  parameter  to be a function of time $t$. The  dependence of intensity parameter on time implies that events are more  likely to occur at certain times compared to other times.

For  example, customers arriving into a bank are not uniform throughout  the business hours; there will be some rush hours and some  leisure hours. In a household,  the number of units of  electricity consumed will vary according to time. The vehicular  traffic on the road will not be uniform throughout the day.

Due  to the dependence of arrival rate on time, the process no longer  has the stationarity property.

This generalization does not effect the form of the distribution of the process, but allows variation in the arrival rate to occur as determined by the function $\lambda(t).$

This can be observed from the following:

Let $G(s,t)$ denote the PGF of the NHPP. Then, by
definition, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
G(s,t+h) & = & E[s^{N(t+h)}] \\
& = & E[s^{N(t+h)-N(t)}\cdot s^{N(t)}]\\
& = & E[s^{N(t+h)-N(t)}] \cdot \underbrace{ E[s^{N(t)}]}_{G(s,t)}\\
& = & G(s,t) \cdot E[s^{N(t+h)-N(t)}]\\
& = & G(s,t)\cdot \left\{ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P\{N(t+h) - N(t)=
k\}\cdot s^{k} \right\}\\
& = & G(s,t)\; \{\; P\{N(t+h)-N(t) = 0 \} \quad + \\
&   & \quad\quad\quad P\{N(t+h)-N(t) = 1 \}\cdot s + \\
&   & \quad\quad\quad \sum_{j=2}^{\infty}P\{N(t+h)-N(t) = j\}
\cdot s^{j}\}\\
& = & G(s,t) \cdot \left[(1-\lambda(t)h + o(h)) + \lambda(t)h
\cdot s + o(h)\right]
\end{eqnarray*}
Transposing $G(s,t)$ to the left hand side and  dividing
throughout by $h$ and letting $h\rightarrow 0$, yields
$$\quad\quad\quad\quad G^{'}(s,t) = -(1-s)\cdot \lambda(t) \cdot G(s,t).$$
$$\frac{G^{'}(s,t)}{G(s,t)} = -(1-s)\cdot \lambda(t)$$
Integrating on both sides, we get
$$\ln G(s,t) = -(1-s)\int_{0}^{t}\lambda(u)du + C(s)$$
$$G(s,t) = \; exp \left\{-(1-s)\int_{0}^{t}\lambda(u)du\right\}A(s)$$
But, $G(s,0) = 1 = A(s).$ Thus,
$$G(s,t) = \;exp\left\{-(1-s)\int_{0}^{t}\lambda(u)du\right\}$$
which is the PGF of a Poisson process with mean
$$E\left\{N(t)\right \}= \int_{0}^{t}\lambda(u)du$$